# R - Table () does not return a 2 way table

Tags: r

I'm using Table() function expecting to get a contingency table but it returns 2 columns and a frequency instead of a 2 way table.

This is what I´m doing:

```
denue <- read.csv("DENUE 2010.csv")
str(denue)

'data.frame':   416898 obs. of  13 variables:  
$ Nombre.de.la.unidad.económica  : chr  "MINERA METALURGICA TAPALPA" "PLANTA DE TRATAMIENTO DE AGUA RECIDUAL" "DESARROLLOS INMOBILIARIOS BMU" 
$ Razón.social                   : chr  "MINERA METALURGICA TAPALPAÂ  S A DE C V"
$ Código.de.la.clase.de.actividad: int  212221 222111 236112 236211 236211 236221
$ Nombre.de.la.clase.de.actividad: Factor w/ 900 levels "ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS
$ Personal.ocupado..estrato.     : chr  "0 A 5 PERSONAS" "6 A 10 PERSONAS" 
$ Entidad.federativa             : chr  "DISTRITO FEDERAL" "DISTRITO FEDERAL" 
$ Municipio                      : Factor w/ 16 levels "ÁLVARO OBREGÓN",..:
$ Clave                          : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...  
$ Localidad                      : chr  "Azcapotzalco" "Azcapotzalco"...  
$ Área.geoestadística.básica     : chr  "0699" "0932" "1023" "0487" ...  
$ Area                           : Factor w/ 2415 levels "0020010","0020025",..:
$ Latitud                        : num  19.5 19.5 19.5 19.5 19.5 ...  
$ Longitud                       : num  -99.2 -99.2 -99.2 -99.2 -99.2 ...

denue <- data.frame(table(denue$Area, denue$Nombre.de.la.clase.de.actividad))

       Var1                          Var2 Freq
1   0020010 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
2   0020025 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
3   002003A ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
4   0020044 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
5   0020097 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
6   002010A ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
7   0020114 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
8   0020129 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
9   0020133 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
10  0020148 ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES    0
```

When what I want is this:

```
        ACABADO DE PRODUCTOS TEXTILES . until 900th Nombre.de.la.clase.de.actividad
0020010
0020025
002003A  
0020044
```

What am I doing wrong?

​

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need `as.data.frame.matrix(table(denue$Area, denue$Nombre.de.la.clase.de.actividad))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the source code of `as.data.frame.table`

> ex <- quote(data.frame(do.call("expand.grid", c(dimnames(provideDimnames(x,
> sep = sep, base = base)), KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors))

So, it expands into a two column data.frame.  Instead, if we want to convert to `data.frame` with the similar structure, change the `table` to `matrix` and do the conversion so that it wont call `as.data.frame.table` instead calls `as.data.frame.matrix` or call `as.data.frame.matrix` directly (because there are several methods for `as.data.frame` (`methods("as.data.frame")`)

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(denue$Area, denue$Nombre.de.la.clase.de.actividad))
```

---

Using a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am))
#   0 1
#0 12 6
#1  7 7
as.data.frame(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am))
#  Var1 Var2 Freq
#1    0    0   12
#2    1    0    7
#3    0    1    6
#4    1    1    7
```

which is same as the method

```
as.data.frame.table(table(mtcars$vs, mtcars$am))
#  Var1 Var2 Freq
#1    0    0   12
#2    1    0    7
#3    0    1    6
#4    1    1    7
```